# Solving quartic equation using substitution

Tags: math-history, quadratics

We are learning a lot about the history of our famous mathematicians and this specific one is stumping me. They want us to solve a problem a specific way and I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Would anyone be able to assist me in how to solve his quartic equation this specific way. 
A dying Italian mathematician revealed to you a secret formula for solving quartic equations of the form $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+c=0$. How would you use it to solve quartic equations of the form $u^4+du^2+fu+g=0$ ($u$ is the unknown here), where $g \not= 0$ ? In other words, what substitution $u=u(x)$ would you use to reduce equations of the form $u^4+du^2+fu+g=0$ to equations of the form $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+c=0$?

Comment: See [Tschirnhaus transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschirnhaus_transformation). Given that this problem was posed to you in the context of math history, I suspect this was the substitution the author of the problem had in mind. But Andre's suggestion is more straightforward I think.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Because $g\ne 0$, $u=0$ is not a solution of our equation. Try the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: That's really more of an answer than a hint, don't you think? :-)

Comment: @BrianTung: To someone with facility in manipulation, sure.

Comment: To be persnickety, OP only asked for the substitution, not how to follow it to its logical conclusion.  (It's certainly useful that you added the stipulation that $g \not= 0$, and isn't it also useful to observe that the polynomial in $u$ is monic?)

Comment: I figure if the substitution is done, the adjustment should not be hard.